# Arrange array based on another array Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have reference array which has values `["a","b","c","d"]` .and i have another array which is obtaining as part of API which is not very consistent format .i am pointing some examples below

```
case 1.`{
     names : ["a"],
     value : [ [0],[0],[2],[4],... ]
   }`
case 2. `{
     names : ["a","c"],
     value : [ [0,2],[0,0],[2,3],[4,4],... ]
    }`
```

the result could be in any combination 
but my requirement is to assign the value of incoming result into another array
having index same as my reference array
for example : in 
case  1

```
`
let finalArray = [["0",null,null,null],
                  ["0",null,null,null], 
                   ["2",null,null,null]....  ]
`
```

for case 2:

```
`let finalArray = [["0",null,"2",null],
                  ["0",null,"0",null], 
                   ["2",null,"3",null]....   ]  
`
```

alse attaching a fiddle with my inputs below

[jsfiddle link to problem](https://jsfiddle.net/harigopalmg/tb5aywjx/9/)

any suggestions?
i am trying to use minimal for loops for performance optimization

Comment: Have you made any attempt to accomplish this yet? Please post what you've tried

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, I think `a, b, c, d` means position `0, 1, 2, 3` of the "value" array

Comment: It's not clear (at least to me) how your desired result is related to what you are starting with.

Comment: Sorry for the confusions , i have updated my fiddle  with my solution also
but as i said before it was not a good solution since i have lakhs thousands of entries in array.
@CertainPerformance ,@MarkMeyer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will be helpful.

```js
var refArray = ["a","b","c","d"];

setTimeout(()=>{processResult({
     "names" : ["a"],
     "value" : [ [0],[0],[2],[4]]
   })},2000);
setTimeout(()=>{processResult(
{
     "names" : ["a","c"],
     "value" : [ [0,2],[0,0],[2,3],[4,4]]
})},4000);
setTimeout(()=>{processResult(
{
     "names" : ["d","c"],
     "value" : [ [0,2],[0,0],[2,3],[4,4]]
})},6000);


function processResult (result) {
    let res = result.value;
    let resArray = res.map((el)=>{
        let k=Array(refArray.length).fill(null);
        refArray.forEach((e,i)=>{
          let indx = result.names.indexOf(e);
          if(indx>=0){       
                k[i] = el[indx]
            }      
        });
        return k;
    })
  console.log("result",resArray) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I could think of that would require least iterations.

```
    var refArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
    setTimeout(()=>{processResult({
         "names" : ["a"],
         "value" : [ [0],[0],[2],[4]]
       })},2000);
    setTimeout(()=>{processResult(
    {
         "names" : ["a","c"],
         "value" : [ [0,2],[0,0],[2,3],[4,4]]
    })},4000);
    setTimeout(()=>{processResult(
    {
         "names" : ["d","c"],
         "value" : [ [0,2],[0,0],[2,3],[4,4]]
    })},6000);


    function processResult(result) {
      //This map will contain max names matched in the result
      var maxItemsFromResult = {};

      //Find the indexes in refArray and fill map
      //e.g. 1st- {0:0}, 2nd - {0:0, 1:2}, 3rd - {0:3, 1:2}
      result.names.forEach((item, index) => {
        let indexFound = refArray.indexOf(item);
        if (indexFound > -1) {
          maxItemsFromResult[index] = indexFound;
        }
      });

      //for performance if no key matched exit
      if (Object.keys(maxItemsFromResult).length < 1) {
        return;
      }
      //This will be final result
      let finalArray = [];

      //Because finalArray's length shuld be total items in value array loop through it
      result.value.forEach((item, itemIndex) => {
        //Create a row
        let valueArray = new Array(refArray.length).fill(null);
        //Below will only loop matched keys and fill respective position/column in row
        //i'm taking all the matched keys from current value[] before moving to next
        Object.keys(maxItemsFromResult).forEach((key, index) => {
          valueArray[maxItemsFromResult[key]] = item[index];//get item from matched key
        });
        finalArray.push(valueArray);
      });
      console.log(finalArray);
      return finalArray;
    }
```